# Android.support.v4 import not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, import

I've seen questions like this, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

I was following the tutorial on how to build an RSS Android parser and reader from [here](http://blog.nerdability.com/2013/03/tech-building-rss-reader-android-app.html). Along the way, some code included importing `fragmentactivity`and `fragment`. Both imports failed. Experimentation showed me that when importing the fragment, it should be imported as

```
    import android.app.fragment;
```

rather than

```
    import android.support.v4.app.fragment;
```

which was in the code for this RSS reader.

Trying the same thing with

```
    import android.app.fragmentactivity;
```

doesn't work, when it calls for

```
    import android.support.v4.app.fragmentactivity;
```

Does anyone know why it's failing to import this properly? Reading the Android Documentation doesn't seem to help. Please let me know if I need to add anything! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the appropriate Android Support Library. Google has a thoroughly written document here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

However, the setup is kind of different depending on your IDE (Eclipse, Android Studio, etc.) From my personal experience, Android Studio is the easiest to get started with the nasty build logistics.

Comment: Yep, I'm on Android Studio.

Comment: Try following the link then. They have detailed instructions on how to import the android.support.v7 library for Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The v4 support library backports the idea of fragments to 2.X devices that don't have them in the framework.  If you want to use fragments and run on 2.X, you must use the support versions and never the built ins.  If you don't care about 2.X, use the builtins.  As for problems importing, did you link in the v4 support library?  You need that library to use the support fragments.

Comment: I'm not totally fluent in Java :) Could you explain a bit more?